# Why is the mysql client utility not using the port I specify?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, port

I'm trying to use `mysql` (command line utility) to connect to MySQL server through SSH tunnel.
The problem is this MySQL client won't use my specified port.
For example, I ran this:

```
$ mysql -uroot --port=1234
```

And it then just connected to port 3306.

Why does it do that?

How can I *force* this client to connect to port 1234 (then it should show me that port 1234 is not connectable).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are running the mysql client on the same host that the server is running, it is probably making a socket connection, and not using the port at all.  Try adding  `--protocol=TCP` to your command

`mysql -uroot --protocol=TCP --port=1234`

Answer (score 4):

If you use TCP/IP you should specify the host IP. If the host is localhost, you must use 127.0.0.1 instead.

In other words

mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P1234 -p (if the root has a password)

mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P1234 (if the root does not has a password)

Once logged in, run this query to make sure:

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port';